# How to not return duplicate values from a generator?

Tags: python, generator, yield

I have a function like below:

```
def fun(content):
    for i in content:
        id = i.split('\"')[0]
        yield id    
    return id
```

The problem is that there are some duplicated values in content.
Is there any way to know if the value 'id' is already in the generator 'id'? Rather than get the final generator then use set()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `set` inside `fun` to keep track of the ids that have been seen already:

```
def fun(content):
    observed = set()
    for i in content:
        id = i.split('\"')[0]
        if id not in observed:
            observed.add(id)
            yield id
```

Also, since you're yielding ids you don't need to return at the end.

Comment: I thought generator would use less memory? if use set() inside, why not just return the final set() ?  I’m confused here.

Comment: A generator will use far less memory, however the only way to ensure that duplicate values do not get output is to keep track of the ones that have been seen in some type of data structure. If you do not need `fun` to be a generator returning jut a set would be simpler and essentially the same.

Comment: got it, Thanks!:)